# Nontrivial solution for Ax=0 and Ax=b determine by pivot positions

Tags: linear-algebra

> A is a 3x2 matrix with two pivot positions.
>
> (a) does the equation Ax=0 have a nontrivial solution

Since the two pivot positions will create 0 in the entire column in which they are present and 1 in its own position in reduced row echelon form and the rightmost column is all 0 therefore Ax=0 has no nontrivial solution

> (b) does the equation Ax=b have atleast one solution for every possible b?

In the reduced row form b should have a [* * 0] form then only a unique non trivial solution exists

Is this correct and does it sound mathematical?

Comment: It sounds hard to understand. What do you mean by "with two pivot positions" ? And if your matrix has three rows by two columns, your $[*\ *\ 0]$ is meaningless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, question is written as it is from the book and [* * 0]  means a column vector with first and second non zero elements and last zero

Comment: I get what you are trying to say, but it is a bit jumbled.  Please have a look at [posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your posts easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to (a) looks good. Question (b) can be asked alternately as $``$Can $\mathbb{R}^3$ be spanned by only two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$$"$?